# Disable a line of code in Android app if signature is verified?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to disable ads in my app if I detect that another one of my (paid) apps are installed.  Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();

    if (manager.checkSignatures("com.example.appone", "com.example.apptwo") == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH == false) {
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest); 
    } else {

    }

    // code continues here
}
```

However, the ads are always on.  I can't get them to turn off - ever.  Did I call `PackageManager` incorrectly?  Or am I just way off base with this idea?

Comment: The check should be just: `if (manager.checkSignatures("com.example.appone", "com.example.apptwo") == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH)`. Isn't it?

Comment: if (manager.checkSignatures("com.example.appone", "com.example.apptwo") != PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH)

Comment: or `== SIGNATURE_NO_MATCH`

Comment: Okay, I changed it to @ben75 's suggestion, and it's still showing ads.  No matter what happens, it shows ads.

Comment: Are you sure that your both apps are installed with the same key (i.e. the debug key from the same computer or the same release key, but not a debug-key and a release-key) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what was going on, but when I picked it back up today at work, the code was returning properly. Thanks for your help, @ben75!